# Docker Swarm response from daemon: attaching to network failed,

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-container, subnet

Given this `docker-compose.yaml` in `/myproject` on an ubuntu host:

```
services:
  alpine:
    image: alpine
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.0.1
networks:
  net:
    name: net
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

On a host with `docker swarm init` run and working, I attempt to deploy the service:

```
docker compose up alpine
```

and get the following output:

```
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Network net          Created                                        0.0s
 ⠿ Container myproject-alpine-1  Created                                        0.3s
Attaching to myproject-alpine-1
Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded
```

How do I check the manager logs?

Running `docker node ls`, the engine version is 23.0.0

```
docker node inspect <my_node>
```

Result includes:

```
"Status": {
    "State": "ready",
    "Addr": "192.168.20.153"
},
"ManagerStatus": {
    "Leader": true,
    "Reachability": "reachable",
    "Addr": "192.168.20.153:2377"
}
```

What I expect to happen is that a new alpine container/service is created with the ip address 172.28.0.1 on a new subnet within a custom overlay network. Is it possible to allocate an IP address on an overlay network like this?

Is my network config incorrect?

Comment: https://github.com/mark-church/docs/blob/master/local-scope-swarm-networking.md#bridge-networking

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/9324/docker-container-and-their-ips-on-overlay-swarm-networks